# Error while switching from Windows to Mac OS flutter mobile app

Tags: flutter, firebase, macos, cocoapods

I can't run my flutter project as pod install gives an error. While It's working fine on my windows laptop. I'm using GitHub repo to clone the project at a new MacBook to try the app using a real iOS device.
Just to let you know, flutter is working fine, I've tested it already using a new projects and it's working, but when I try to use pod install or update to get the dependencies, it starts complaining like the following.

```
[!] CDN: trunk Repo update failed - 207 error(s):
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.0.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.0.5/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.0.7/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.0.9/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.10/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.11/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.12/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.2/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.3/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.4/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.5/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.6/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.7/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.9/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.2.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.2.2/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.2.3/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.0.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.1.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.11.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.12.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.13.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.4.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.7.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.8.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.0.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.0.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.0.2/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.0.3/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.1.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.1.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.1.2/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.2.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.2.2/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.3.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.3.2/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.3.3/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.4.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.4.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.4.1.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.4.2/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.4.3/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.5.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.11.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.11.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.12.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.13.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.14.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.15.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.16.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.17.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.2.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: Couldn't connect to server
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.4.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: Couldn't connect to server
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.5.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.5.2/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.7.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.7.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.8.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.0.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.0.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.0.2/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.0.3/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.0.4/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.1.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.1.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.10.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.11.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.12.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.13.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: Couldn't connect to server
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.4.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: Couldn't connect to server
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.7.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.8.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.8.2/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: Couldn't connect to server
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.0.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.0.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.1.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.11.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.12.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.13.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.14.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.15.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.16.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.17.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: Couldn't connect to server
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.18.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.19.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.20.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: Couldn't connect to server
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.20.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.20.2/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.4.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.4.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: Couldn't connect to server
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.7.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.8.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.8.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.0.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.1.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.11.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.12.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.13.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.14.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.15.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.16.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.17.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.18.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: Couldn't connect to server
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.19.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.20.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.21.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.22.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: Couldn't connect to server
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.23.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.24.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.25.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.26.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: Couldn't connect to server
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.27.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.27.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.28.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.28.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.29.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.30.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.31.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: Couldn't connect to server
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.31.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.32.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.32.2/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.33.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.34.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.4.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.7.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.8.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.8.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.0.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.1.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.11.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.2.0-M1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.3.0-M1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.4.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.4.0-M1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.7.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.8.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.8.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.9.0-k1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.9.0-k2/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.0.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.1.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.1.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.11.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.12.1/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.13.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.14.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.15.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.4.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error

.
.
.
```

I don't know what is wrong and I couldn't find any solution. I've tried the following :

---

`pod repo remove trunk` then re update, nothing.
Then `pod repo add master https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` which took about 20 minutes so I had to cancel it.

```
pod cache clean --all
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

still nothing.

Comment: Could be problem with your podfile, version of cocoapods or a number of other things. Can you include your podfile and version in the question?

Comment: For real, it was just the internet connection in Egypt. You need to use VPN to make it work like I wanna download a forbidden things omg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem before and i used VPN